# Evaluating the mark-up

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Even after giving a discount of $20\%$, a shopkeeper makes a profit of $10\%$. Find the mark-up $\%$ ?

$(1) \ 30\%  $

$(2) \ 35\% $

$(3) \ 37.5\% $

$(4) \ 40 \%  $

$(5) \ \text{None of these}$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? Do you exclude any of the above, and why? Do you believe the correct answer isn't listed?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Let say the mark-up is $t$, then you may write
$$
(1-0.20)\times(1+t)=(1+0.10)
$$ or

> $$
> 0.8+0.8\times t=1.1
> $$

then it is easy to get $t$.